# emulator-x86.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am getting these error at `console`.

`hax is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode eclipse`.

So I am  unable to run the app in emulator.

Comment: Closing other direct x programs fixed it. I had a game application running alongside the emulator which caused this issue. (If your AVD is using host GPU)

Comment: For me, a reboot did the trick.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After spending a lot of time,I am come up with the answer.

- **If you are getting  emulator-x86.exe has stopped working Error means:**

  > Try these `two` steps:
  >
  > > 1. Change the resolution of the device `1280X800 to 800X600.`
  > > 2. Reduce the size of the Ram by `512 MB or less.`
- **If you are getting Hax is not working Error means**:

  > Try these three steps:
  >
  > > 1.Hax software would be located
  > >         in
  > >
  > > `C:\Program
  > >     Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`
  > >
  > > Install the HAXM Driver by running "IntelHaxm.exe" in command Prompt.
  > >
  > > 2.. if the installer fails with message that Intel VT must be turned on,
  > >         you need to enable this in *BIOS*.
  > >
  > > ```
  > > For Eg:
  > > ```
  > >
  > > if You are using windows 7, press F12 key to enter into bios setting.
  > >         There you can see the `Intel Virtualization Technology placed in System Performance`.Turn it **on** as enabled
  > >
  > > 3.Then again run the "IntelHaxm.exe" in command Prompt.Everything will be works fine.

Comment: @Naruto how to decrease the amount of ram?

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio, AVD Manager, edit the AVD you want and disable Use Host GPU under Emulated Performance. This eliminated this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this by un-selecting Multi-Core CPU.