# error message "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using windows 7 with 4GB of RAM and I'm using the latest version of android studio `2.2.3` and I am getting this message when I run the emulator

> "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working"

I tried minimizing ram and resolution and it didn't work, also haxm is installed, could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I'm working on 2 screens, somehow the emulator crashes on my second screen, I don't have the slightest clue why.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's an annoying issue with hardly any solutions up for graps online.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue solved it by changing the Emulated Performance to Software GLES-2.0,I saw previous post and tried using Host GPU but since that option is not available in my Android Studio(2.2.3). I tried this and it worked

[image]

Comment: on my Windows 10, setting the GPU to "software" emulation stops the emulator from booting. I have it set to "Hardware" instead of "Auto" and qemu hasn't frozen up yet

Comment: update - setting it to hardware caused it to freeze again :-/

Answer (score 4):

My emulator was working perfectly, then suddenly it started giving the same problem. So, I tried some methods, and one of them worked. I am mentioning from less to more (timewise) solutions. They are:

1. In AVD Edit -> change the Emulated Performance to Software GLES 2.0. (This dint work for me, but for some it can work).
2. Go to Control Panel -> H/W and Sounds -> Device Manager -> Display adapter -> Your Display Driver -> Right click and update it. (This worked for me and got the emulator running nicely).
3. In AVD Manager -> In your AVD change resolution to 800x600 and reduce RAM size to 512 MB or less. (Would have tried this solution next). [emulator-x86.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328402/emulator-x86-exe-has-stopped-working)
4. Try creating a new AVD which consumes less memory and resolution.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem occur after using the same emulator for a while with no issues. What solved it for me was in **AVD Manager > Actions** select:

1) Wipe data

2) Cold boot.

Comment: For me, the option to pick how to emulate the AVD was disabled so couldn't follow solution posted by Raja Ravi Theja. This is what worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Win7, makes me wonder if you have a compatible processor.
The first requirement for qemu-system is
Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality.

I get this message when the "Memory and Storage RAM: is set to low.
The message went way when I upped it to 6gigs. I still get the "Processing System has stopped" message, but this doesn't stop the emulator from loading. I also get the Google Play has stopped, but this too goes away after a bit and my app loads.
It takes around 20 minutes for the emulator to finish and load my app.

I suggest you start with the smallest Device with the lowest screen resolution, like the NEXUS S 480x800.
I tried several solutions from this site, none made a difference till I tried the opposite of one solution, that was to up the memory for the emulator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 7 X64, 4gb of RAM with dual core. Studio 2.3.3
I'll avoid studio emulator, Rather go with CMD.

You will get the ERROR why `qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working`

My ERROR:

***emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.***

then
**USE command:**

`emulator.exe @YourAVDName -gpu off`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I selected too much RAM in the Advanced Options when setting up the emulator. Selecting the default amount of RAM fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because your pc's hardware does not support it.
Change the Graphics in AVD Manager to Software GLES2.0, but it will still take forever to start the Emulator.
You can always opt for 3rd party emulators such as [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com).

Answer (score 0):

It was solved when I wiped the emulator data.

Go to **AVD Manager**, click on the arrow next to your device and select **wipe data**:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This error came up after I installed windows 11 and apparently it's not compatible yet.

I noticed the author of this question is using windows 7, but hopefully it would help those who are using windows 11.

This problem would most likely cease to exist after windows made an update, but for the meantime, here is the tutorial on how to fix it.

1. Basically you need to find out what version of windows support android studio, I found that out by clicking `run`.
   [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnuMb.png)
2. Windows would then scan all the programs you have installed on your computer.
3. Click on android studio [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCIrv.png)
4. Click `Try recommended settings`
5. Windows would then pick the version that is compatible, in my case, it was windows 8. [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nz4p.png)
6. You have to pick the option to test the program first or just click `Next`
7. After that, just follow what windows is telling you to do and everything would work just fine

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me.

```
./emulator -avd <your AVD Name> -gpu off
```

Refer to see the type of error I got and that highlighted command resolved the problem
[image]