# when i am trying to open the emulator in android am getting the error like qemu-system-x86-64 has stopped working

Tags: android

I'm unable to run the emulator because of this issue. Although I tried to change the resolution and size of the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error message "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974849/error-message-qemu-system-i386-exe-has-stopped-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possibility when emulator doesn't start.
but major of them is as below you have to update Emulated performance Graphics as (Software) ..
[image]

Hope this will be useful for you..

Answer (score 0):

**Try these two steps:**

1. the resolution of the device 1280X800 to 800X600.
2. Reduce the size of the Ram by 512 MB or less.