# AVD Manager: can't see "wipe data" or "Emulated Performance"?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-virtual-device

I'm getting error message `qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working` when debugging Xamarin.Forms app.

Searching the web, I found this solution: [error message "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974849/error-message-qemu-system-i386-exe-has-stopped-working). It basically says to "Wipe Data" and/or change Emulated Performance to *Software GLES 2.0*

The problem is that I don't see the options "Wipe Data" in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2EVF.png) and I don't see *AVD Edit -> change the Emulated Performance to Software GLES 2.0.*

Am I missing something?

This is the screen I'm seeing when I go to `Android Device Manager` and click *Edit*. I don't see anything there that says "Wipe Data" or "Emulated Performance".

I have `Visual Studio 2017 15.9.5`.

[image]

Comment: The screen you are comparing it to is from Android Studio, not VS/Xamarin. You can use the `emulator.exe`'s cmd-line to `-wipe-data` (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) or install Android Studio (it's tools are useful in filling the holes where the VS/Xamarin Android one fall short.)

Comment: Have you tried to delete the emulator and create a new device to retry it?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but this is my 3rd day on this and I assumed I could run the most basic mobile app with only the Visual Studio installation.

Comment: It seems that Windows 7 is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Tools --> Android --> Android Device Manager --> Right click device --> Factory reset

[image]

Comment: how to remove duplicate emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, unable to find wipe data action anywhere. Factory reset doesn't work for me. My problem is "To Start Android, enter your password" but i didnt found any ways to solve it without wipe data. This steps has solved this issure:

1. Run **cmd.exe** as administrator
2. My **android-sdk** folder location is **E:\Android\android-sdk**, so change it to **E:\Android\android-sdk\tools**
3. There is emulator.exe file, run it with **emulator.exe -list-avds** parameter for find your real avd names.
4. Now, if you have got your avd in list run **emulator.exe -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME -wipe-data**

Here is what i have:

[image: Wipe data demonstration]