# Emulator "will run unaccelerated" and qemu-system error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-7, visual-studio-2017

We have Windows 7 (x64) at work, and I wanted to learn about Xamarin.Forms. Specifically, I wanted to create a very basic app that will eventually run in an iphone and Android.

I installed VS2017 and tried running [Build your first Xamarin.Forms App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows). I get this warning, but click on "Start Anyway":

[image]

The emulator pops up, but after a few seconds I get error message `qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working`:

[image]

I'm new to mobile apps development and Xamarin.Forms (3 days to be exact). With that said, I googled possible solutions, and I found this [error message "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974849/error-message-qemu-system-i386-exe-has-stopped-working) and other questions with similar solutions.

The problem is that the solution requires that I download Android Studio, and I don't want to download anything else until I see something run from VS2017.

I tried running `emulator.exe -avd "Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo" -wipe-data` and yet another error:

[image]

Finally, I tried installing Hyper-V manager using this [Microsoft TechNet link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/schadinio/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7/), but I don't have the option *Remote Server Administration Tools*.

What can I do next? I'm pretty much ready to give up on Xamarin in Windows 7. I still haven't been able to debug an application.

After enabling `Intel Virtualization` in the BIOS and installing and making sure `intelhaxm` is running, I opened the project and ran it again.

The "Performance Warning" popup doesn't show up anymore, and there's progress with the android emulator, but it still crashes. This is the screenshot now:

[image]

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration for more information on this topic. Your best bet since you are on Windows 7 is to use HAXM over Hyper-V.

Comment: Thanks. I installed HAXM and `intelhaxm` is set to `RUNNING`.

Comment: I don't see the performance warning anymore, and the I can see the Android emulator, but I still get `qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working`

Comment: First, make sure you installed HAXM and disabled Hyper-V. Refer here [hardware-acceleration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/android-sdk-emulator/hardware-acceleration/). Second, open `Android Device Manager` --> right click on the `emulator` --> choose `Duplicate and Edit` --> Choose `hw.gpu.mode` -->Change the value from `auto` to `mesa` or `swiftshader`. Try it to see if it will solve your problem.