# Android emulator pop and display qemu error

Tags: android, emulation

[This is the screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pxrs.png)
I was unable to run my app using android studio emulator.i use my phone as emulator and work perfectly but anytime i use emulator it get displaying a message i did not understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - [StackOverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328402/emulator-x86-exe-has-stopped-working)

Comment: use genymotion instead of official emulator

Comment: how will i use that